# JQuery Accordion - Last Cell Flip Sides

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I really didn't know how to come up with a descriptive title for this. Pretty much what I'm trying to do is make this accordion list item jump to the other side of the page when clicked. Currently the accordion is opening from left to right - but the last cell doesn't jump right it instead stays in place. How can I make that last cell jump to the right instead of staying in place.

The point of this is to put a picture in the tabs and have them come together at the beginning and end of browsing links.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DYEwB/1/) - click the last cell

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Accordion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="redo.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hc1" class="haccordion">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="hpanel">
                    <div class="preview" id="p1"></div>
                    <div class="contentContainer">
                        <div class="content">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="hpanel">
                    <div class="preview" id="p2"></div>
                    <div class="contentContainer">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="hpanel">
                    <div class="preview" id="p3"></div>
                    <div class="contentContainer">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="hpanel">
                    <div class="preview" id="p4"></div>
                    <div class="contentContainer">
                    asdf
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="hpanel">
                    <div class="preview" id="p5"></div>
                    <div class="contentContainer">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="accordion.js"></script>
<!-- End Scripts -->
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
*
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px
}

html, body
{
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#hc1, #hc1 ul, #hc1 li
{
    height: 100%;
}

#hc1, #hc1 ul 
{
    width: 100%;
}

.preview
{
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #E48525
}

#p1{background-color: #231F20}
#p2{background-color: #4F4E4F}
#p3{background-color: #919191}
#p4{background-color: #C4C4C3}
#p5{background-color: #E8E8E8}
/*
#p1{background-color: red}
#p2{background-color: blue}
#p3{background-color: green}
#p4{background-color: black}
#p5{background-color: orange}
*/
.contentContainer
{
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* -- Start Accordion -- */
.haccordion{
padding: 0;
}

.haccordion ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
overflow: hidden; /*leave as is*/
}

.haccordion li{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: block; /*leave as is*/
overflow: hidden; /*leave as is*/
float: left; /*leave as is*/
}
/* -- End Accordion -- */
```

**Javascript**

```
var haccordion={
    //customize loading message if accordion markup is fetched via Ajax:
    ajaxloadingmsg: '<div style="margin: 1em; font-weight: bold"><img src="ajaxloadr.gif" style="vertical-align: middle" /></div>',

    accordioninfo: {}, //class that holds config information of each haccordion instance

    expandli:function(accordionid, targetli){
        var config=haccordion.accordioninfo[accordionid]
        var $targetli=(typeof targetli=="number")? config.$targetlis.eq(targetli) : (typeof targetli=="string")? jQuery('#'+targetli) : jQuery(targetli)
        if (typeof config.$lastexpanded!="undefined") //targetli may be an index, ID string, or DOM reference to LI
        {
            config.$lastexpanded.stop().animate({width:config.paneldimensions.peekw}, config.speed); //contract last opened content
            config.$lastexpanded.removeClass('active');
        }
        $targetli.stop().animate({width:$targetli.data('hpaneloffsetw')}, config.speed) //expand current content
        config.$lastexpanded=$targetli
        if($targetli.attr('class') != 'active')
        $targetli.addClass('active');
    },


    urlparamselect:function(accordionid){
        var result=window.location.search.match(new RegExp(accordionid+"=(\\d+)", "i")) //check for "?accordionid=index" in URL
        if (result!=null)
            result=parseInt(RegExp.$1)+"" //return value as string so 0 doesn't test for false
        return result //returns null or index, where index is the desired selected hcontent index
    },

    getCookie:function(Name){
        var re=new RegExp(Name+"=[^;]+", "i") //construct RE to search for target name/value pair
        if (document.cookie.match(re)) //if cookie found
            return document.cookie.match(re)[0].split("=")[1] //return its value
        return null
    },

    setCookie:function(name, value){
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; path=/"
    },


    loadexternal:function($, config){ //function to fetch external page containing the entire accordion content markup
        var $hcontainer=$('#'+config.ajaxsource.container).html(this.ajaxloadingmsg)
        $.ajax({
            url: config.ajaxsource.path, //path to external content
            async: true,
            error:function(ajaxrequest){
                $hcontainer.html('Error fetching content.<br />Server Response: '+ajaxrequest.responseText)
            },
            success:function(content){
                $hcontainer.html(content)
                haccordion.init($, config)
            }
        })
    },


    init:function($, config){
            haccordion.accordioninfo[config.accordionid]=config //cache config info for this accordion
            var $targetlis=$('#'+config.accordionid).find('ul:eq(0) > li') //find top level LIs
            config.$targetlis=$targetlis
            config.selectedli=config.selectedli || [] //set default selectedli option
            config.speed=config.speed || "normal" //set default speed

//KEY_CHANGE_BEGIN
            var maxWidth    = $targetlis.parent ().width ();
            $targetlis.each ( function () { maxWidth -= $(this).outerWidth (true); } );

            $targetlis.each(function(i){
                var $target=$(this).data('pos', i) //give each li an index #

                var lclMaxWidth     = maxWidth + $target.find ('.hpanel:eq(0)').outerWidth (true);
                $target.css ('width', config.paneldimensions.fullw);

                //get offset width of each .hpanel DIV (config.dimensions.fullw + any DIV padding)
                var hpaneloffsetw   = $target.find ('.hpanel:eq(0)').outerWidth (true);
                if (hpaneloffsetw > lclMaxWidth)
                    hpaneloffsetw   = lclMaxWidth;

                $target.data('hpaneloffsetw', hpaneloffsetw);
                $target.css ('width', '');
//KEY_CHANGE_END

                $target.click(function(){
                        haccordion.expandli(config.accordionid, this)
                    config.$lastexpanded=$(this);
                })
                if (config.collapsecurrent){ //if previous content should be contracted when expanding current
                        config.$lastexpanded.removeClass('active');
                    $target.click(function(){
                        $(this).stop().animate({width:config.paneldimensions.peekw}, config.speed); //contract previous content
                    })
                }
            }) //end $targetlis.each
            var selectedli=haccordion.urlparamselect(config.accordionid) || ((config.selectedli[1] && haccordion.getCookie(config.accordionid))? parseInt(haccordion.getCookie(config.accordionid)) : config.selectedli[0])
            selectedli=parseInt(selectedli)
            if (selectedli>=0 && selectedli<config.$targetlis.length){ //if selectedli index is within range
                config.$lastexpanded=$targetlis.eq(selectedli)
                config.$lastexpanded.css('width', config.$lastexpanded.data('hpaneloffsetw')) //expand selected li
            }
            $(window).bind('unload', function(){ //clean up and persist on page unload
                haccordion.uninit($, config)
            }) //end window.onunload
    },

    uninit:function($, config){
        var $targetlis=config.$targetlis
        var expandedliindex=-1 //index of expanded content to remember (-1 indicates non)
        $targetlis.each(function(){
            var $target=$(this)
            $target.unbind()
            if ($target.width()==$target.data('hpaneloffsetw'))
                expandedliindex=$target.data('pos')
        })
        if (config.selectedli[1]==true) //enable persistence?
            haccordion.setCookie(config.accordionid, expandedliindex)
    },

    setup:function(config){
        //Use JS to write out CSS that sets up initial dimensions of each LI, for JS enabled browsers only
        document.write('<style type="text/css">\n')
        document.write('#'+config.accordionid+' li{width: '+config.paneldimensions.peekw+';\nheight: '+config.paneldimensions.h+';\n}\n')
        document.write('#'+config.accordionid+' li .hpanel{width: '+config.paneldimensions.fullw+';\nheight: '+config.paneldimensions.h+';\n}\n')
        document.write('<\/style>')
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //on Dom load
            if (config.ajaxsource) //if config.ajaxsource option defined
                haccordion.loadexternal($, config)
            else
                haccordion.init($, config)
        }) //end DOM load
    }
}

haccordion.setup({
    accordionid: 'hc1', //main accordion div id
    paneldimensions: {peekw:'50px', fullw:'100%', h:'100%'},
    selectedli: [4, false], //[selectedli_index, persiststate_bool]
    collapsecurrent: false //<- No comma following very last setting!
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by jump to the otherside of the page when clicked? Do you have an example of desired behaviour, whether that be flash or just image?

Comment: well right now when u click the last cell (the darkest cell) it pushes everything to the right to show the content - what i want it to do is instead is move that cell to the right so that all the cells are on the right

Comment: Anything like this? http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/haccordion.htm

Comment: or are you saying you want the darkest one to now be the first cell?

Comment: I believe I'm actually using that. OK. If you go to the JSFiddle link and view the accordion: At first all the cells are on the Left. When you click through each cell they start moving to the right side of the screen. When you click on the last cell (The left most cell) it stays in place - what I want to do is when you click on the left most cell (the darkest cell) I'm trying to get it to move to the right side with all the other cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is: tinker.io/f7fe4/12

This is the simplest change of all of the versions, requiring only floating the first preview to the right. Can be done programatically or with css (can be buggy in IE7+):

```
$('#hc1 li .preview').first().css('float','right');
```

or

```
#hc1 li:first-child .preview {
    float:right;
}
```

--

Is this the kind of effect you're looking for?

https://tinker.io/f7fe4/8

Here's the same kind of affect, with a 'smoother' animation (it keeps the outer div still on the screen however)

https://tinker.io/f7fe4/9

And this is what I thought you were talking about at first

https://tinker.io/f7fe4/4  (this pops the left most cell over to the right  and opens it, kind of like an infinite slider)

Comment: Sort of but when I click the last tab - all the other tabs disappear, at least in chrome anyway.

Comment: So all of the other tabs dissapear, and it slides right? Clicking again "opens" it up again?

Comment: The problem with https://tinker.io/f7fe4/9 is that the last cell is in turn the "Body" of the document. I mean if I make a background color of the body then it shows up in the last cell instead of the list item.

Comment: I thought the effect was something like "closing" an accordion, kind of like this: https://tinker.io/f7fe4/10 . Are you saying you want all of them to slide off, but leave the first one still that big?

Comment: The effect I'm trying to accomplish when I click the last cell of the accordion is to A) Show the content of that cell which in this case would be P5's Content Container and B) Push all the Cell Previews to the right side of the screen and finally C) When I click the first cell again it will transition all the Cell Previews back to the Left. I'm trying to keep all the Cell Previews bunched when your at the beginning or the end of the accordion. If Your viewing the last cell: the previews would be on the right. If your viewing the first cell: all the previews would be on the left.

Comment: So when clicked, the left one would look like: http://flockdraw.com/lj4xv ? feel free to draw/chat on there as well, I'm confident I can make what you want, I just need to have a good understanding first

Comment: This one works how I was thinking. tinker.io/f7fe4/12 -- Can you update your answer with an explanation of what you did to achieve it please?